# bash script that handles optional arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bashscript that expects an optional argument as follows, there are several things that I would like to refine it so that I can pass in the first argument in different ways(0, false to indicate a false value, all other string to indicate true, defaults to false), what's an elegant way to script this? I would like to use if statement with the right boolean expression.

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    update_httpconf="$1";
fi
if [ "$update_httpconf" = "true" ]; then
    echo "hi";
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made it so that making the first argument `--update-httpconf` counts as true, and anything else counts as false, it would be more consistent with other unixey command line utilities.

This might be a good starting point:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        '--update-httpconf')
            update_httpconf=true
            ;;
        *)
            echo "unrecognised arg $1"; exit
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: I can't really understand what's going on here. Would somebody care to explain?

Comment: It's iterating over command line arguments.`$#` evaluates to the number of command line arguments remaining; at the end of the loop I call `shift`, which discards the argument at the front of the list. In each loop, we match on `$1`, which is the command line argument at the front of the list. If `$1` is `--update-httpconf` then we set the variable `update_httpconf` to `true`. The `*` pattern is a catch-all for the `case` statement, so if we reach it, then it means an unrecognised argument was encountered, so we should probably fail and exit the program.

Comment: Nice piece of code. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` statement:

```
case "$1" in
  0|false|FALSE) do_something;;
  *) do_something_else;;
esac
```